Facebook login with business accounts
I am Integrating "Login with Facebook" in my React application, whenever user logged in I am getting Access token, Business ID, Business Name but I also want to get the PhoneID provided by Meta for Particular Business account. How can Retrieve PhoneID?
I have tried fetching mobile data using below API.
 window.FB.api(
      `/${businessID}`,
      { access_token: accessToken, fields: "id,name,phone" },
      (businessDetailsResponse) => {
        console.log(`FB.api /${businessID} response`, businessDetailsResponse);
        if (businessDetailsResponse && !businessDetailsResponse.error) {
          const businessPhone = businessDetailsResponse.phone;
          console.log("Business Phone:", businessPhone);
          // Process and use the phone number as needed
        } else {
          console.error(
            "Error fetching business details:",
            businessDetailsResponse.error
          );
        }
      }
    );
  };

But I am getting Below error.
Error fetching business details: {
  message: '(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (phone) on node type (Business)', 
  type: 'OAuthException', 
  code: 100, 
  fbtrace_id: 'ANdXOI27y432bEWRIDXzpeN'}


https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/ doesn't list a phone field, so I am not sure what exactly you want to access here. Are you talking about pre-verified phone numbers (in a WhatsApp integration context) perhaps? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/preverified_numbers/
